# Building a non linear ascending function that passes through 0,0 and an arbitrary point that grows fast at the beginning and very slow at the end.

Tags: functions

I need to build a function for one of my games to be applied to my player experience. The domain of the experience is $[0, +\infty)$ but I need to constrain the function to pass through an exact point $(x,y)$.

The player is rewarded a semi random quantity of experience depending on the number of objectives he has completed. As you see, there's not a limit on the total quantity of experience he can get. But, I want to reward the player with high quantities at the beginning and low quantities at the end.

Another constraint exists and it is that I need to be able to make this function pass through a point $(x,y)$ that I will change over time as my game grows.

As an example, at this time I need my function pass through $(100, 10000)$ because I want to make sure that when the player completes $100$ objectives it must have $10000$ points of experience. Later I will tweak this as more objectives are added.

I would be happy with something like a logarithmic behavior because of its strong growing nature at the beginning and slow one at the end but wasn't able to construct anything usable around it.

How would you build something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about $y = a{\sqrt x} + b x$? Then suppose you want $x=100$ objectives to yield $y=10,000 $ points, you need to choose $a, b$ such that $10,000 = a\sqrt(100)+b100$. For example, $b=0, a=1000$ will give $y=1000\sqrt x$. You can play with desmos to fine tune. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dyaear5la1

Comment: Well, with small tweaks could work but how can I make it pass through a point? I suppose a function with only one variable can't be forced to pass through a specific point. Am I right?

Comment: you have 2 parameters, a and b

Comment: Sorry if this question is too basic but can't see how to make it pass through for example (10,10). You have a, b but just an equation. How would you do to guess both if a is not equal to b?

Comment: @Notbad you believe $a\sqrt{10} + 10b = 10$ has no solutions?

Comment: @Notbad I expanded on the answer, see if it is clearer now.